# Vim check if second line is 'To:' and empty

Tags: regex, function, vim

I'm looking for something to put into the vimrc file that runs on startup. I need to check the 2nd line of the file that it opens for:

```
To:
```

That's to and a space, basically those word's and then nothing after it. If it finds an "empty" `To:` it takes me to that line at the end, line 2. If `To:` has text after it then it takes me to line 9.

I use Vim for editing emails in Mutt, and I'm trying to get it to decide if I'm replying to an email (the email address is already there) or creating a new email (I need to enter an address) and take me to the appropriate line.

Not quite sure where to even start with this, I don't know if I can run function's on startup in the vimrc and how to tell it to go to the end of X line.  I know I can go to a line with:

```
2gg
```

but the end of the line and the regex is the hard part for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function MuttEnter()
    let l2=getline(2)
    if l2[:3] is# 'To: '
        if len(l2)==3
            2
        else
            9
        endif
        startinsert!
    endif
endfunction
augroup vimrcMutt
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * call MuttEnter()
augroup END
```

. Note: it makes sense to have better detection of whether you are editing a mutt message (currently it assumes you do if you have `To:` (with a space) on the second line).

By the way, you need exactly no regular expressions here, Vim is not as good at optimizing them as perl.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks. Here I thought a regex was needed because of the space and all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this autocommand (see `:help autocmd`)

```
au FileType mail if getline(2) == "To: " | 2 | else | 9 | endif | start!
```

### Step by step:

1. `au` - begin an autocmd. This should be inside an `augroup` and the first line of that `augroup` should be `au!`. This is to prevent errors when resourcing your `.vimrc`.
2. `FileType` - this is an event trigger. See `:help FileType`
3. `mail` - this is the filetype to run this command on. This is set to mail by default in mutt.
4. `getline(2) == "To: "` - if line 2 is equal to `"To: "`
5. `2` - then go to line two. The `|` or `<Bar>` in vim is not a pipe. Instead it acts more like a semi-colon from other languages. It allows you to separate statements, however there are some statements it does not work with, like `:norm`.
6. `else | 9` - otherwise go to line nine
7. `endif` - close the if statement
8. `start!` - begin insert mode at the end of the line.

Comment: I couldn't get the au to work, but the one below worked great. Thanks! :)

Comment: That's odd; it works for me. Perhaps check `set filetype?` inside a mutt message to see if the filetype is set to `mail`. Also make sure you're putting this in your .vimrc

Comment: Yeah I checked that first and it rightfully printed out filetype=mail, so not sure why but it doesn't work with that in front :(

Comment: You probably need `filetype plugin on` in front of it.

Comment: You could change `FileType mail` to `VimEnter *` like the other answer and it would work; however, that runs the command every time you open vim (for any file). I don't think that's what you want.