# VIM Tab then goto line if line not empty

Tags: function, vim, if-statement, mutt

I have been trying this now for about an hour and I can't seem to get it to work at all! ha ha

This is what I have:

```
function! Tabber()
let l2=getline(".")
if l2[:2] == 'To:'
    if len(l2) > 4
        exe "silent! normal 5Gi"
    else
        exe "silent! normal 2Gi"
    endif
endif
startinsert
endfunction
```

Basically when I'm writing an email in VIM for mutt I want to be able to hit the Tab key when done writing the To: address and I want it to decide if the line I'm on has To: on it, then if it's more than 4 character's that mean's I have an address entered, if not then stay there. If there are more than 4 goto line 5 which is the subject line.

Once done there I want to copy that If for a Subject line to make sure if I'm on the subject line goto line 9 to write the email. So I can just tab my way down ha ha.

For the life of me it won't work. Of course I don't have it connected to tab yet, I am just `<Esc>`ing out and then:

```
:call Tabber()
```

But that should work. :S

Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM check if second line is TO and empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871748/vim-check-if-second-line-is-to-and-empty)

Comment: Actually no, that's what started it, that function work's great and is somewhere else in my VimRC. This is a brand new function I am trying to get to work for another use but related to that original since I got my code from it.

Comment: It just doesn't work, it won't move lines at all. I tried making both line 1 to run like a check to see if it was even doing anything and it's not moving at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does work for me, so I'm not sure why you're having trouble with it without some more information. I did modify it though to fit your specifications:

```
function! Tabber()
   let line=getline(".")
   if line[:2] == 'To:'
      if len(line) > 4 | 5 | endif
   elseif line[:7] == 'Subject:'
      if len(line) > 9 | 9 | endif
   endif
   startinsert!
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <Esc>:call Tabber()<cr>
```

Comment: Now that works! What was making mine not work?! The only thing that doesn't work on that one is the <Tab> in Insert mode, I guess I could use another key combo.

Comment: It's probably preferable to use a `<leader>` key in insert mode. See `:help <leader>`.

Comment: You might check `:imap <Tab>` to see if something else is mapped to it. In my case, the snipMate plugin is occupying it.

Comment: Ohhh yeah, I do use snipMate, I forgot about it :(  I'll find another then :)  What's the <Leader> for, I've never found out how to use that?